# Best place to do a check for auth session is still alive in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am building an app which is using native (iOS and Android) framework to do an authentication. I created a plugin which wraps all framework exposed methods to flutter. I have to check every screen change that user is authenticated and session is alive and if not call framework to do so, what will be the best place in flutter to do such check?

Answer (score 1):

Inside a widget. 
Widgets are nearly always where you want to put your logic.

To be exact, what you want is a StatefulWidget that expose an InheritedWidget using a custom `static MyInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context)` method. InheritedWidget which will possess all the login informations and a few "onChange" methods.

You will then be able to access *anywhere* inside your app to this InheritedWidget using `MyAuth.of(context)` and therefore have access to all the needed data.

Usually you'll end up with this :

```
/// The user data model. May be serializable. Usually immutable
@immutable
class MyUser {
  const MyUser({this.name});

  final String name;
}

/// The entry point of your global logic.
/// Most of the time, will only take one child as parameter
/// and nothing else. And will also expose a [of] method
class MyAuth extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const MyAuth({this.child});

  /// Fetch the closest [_MyInheritedAuth] from the widget tree
  /// using context. And bind the widget possessing that context
  /// to reload evytimes the inherited widget changes
  static _MyInheritedAuth of(BuildContext context) {
    final _MyInheritedAuth inherited = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_MyInheritedAuth);
    return inherited;
  }

  @override
  _MyAuthState createState() => new _MyAuthState();
}

typedef void MyUserNameChange(String name);
/// Your controller. Will handle all the logic and just
/// pass it all to [_MyInheritedAuth]
class _MyAuthState extends State<MyAuth> {
  MyUser user;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = const MyUser(name: 'foo');
  }

  void onUserNameChange(String name) {
    setState(() {
      user = new MyUser(name: name);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new _MyInheritedAuth(user: user, editUserName: onUserNameChange, child: widget.child,);
  }
}

/// What the other widgets will get when user [MyAuth.of].
/// Inherit from [InheritedWidget] to be able to bind a context
/// to this widget's updates/
class _MyInheritedAuth extends InheritedWidget {
  final MyUser user;
  final MyUserNameChange editUserName;

  const _MyInheritedAuth({ @required this.user, @required this.editUserName, @required Widget child,}): super(child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_MyInheritedAuth oldWidget) {
    return user != oldWidget.user || editUserName != oldWidget.editUserName;
  }
}
```

And whenever you need to use user infos, you can just do `MyAuth.of(context).user`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The biggest problem which I am facing is not how to hold Auth State and access it, it is what the best time to check it. 
Because I need to check every screen change that session is alive or close to be renewed and have to open Activity from Auth framework which has native implementation. If I am trying to do it from initState() I am getting exception from flutter's Navigator

Comment: What is your exception ?